# Placing quotes in a c# string

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I've got a bit of a weird one here (well I think that it's weird!).

I'm using a web service to return a string and I'm trying to put quotes inside the string so say for instance I want to return the string Craig says, "hello" I would normally do something like:

```
zString = "Craig says, \"Hello\"";
```

but what I'm actually getting back from the webservice is the string including the \'s. So I actually get back:

Craig says, \"Hello\"

This is driving me loopy! Any ideas anyone? Could this declaration at the start be causing the problem?

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the text displayer in the debugger adding the escape chars?

Comment: That is becuase of json format. Double quotes alone, are invalide charachters

Comment: @MatthewWatson is probably right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Being in [JSON format, it also escapes the `"` characters by using `\` when returned.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627)

It's the same as:

```
{
    "zString": "Craig says, \"Hello\""
}
```

Comment: @MatthewWatson So is there any way to remove these \'s?

Comment: that is a matter of where/how do you use the response? where did you see that *Craig says, \"Hello\"* that you said?

Comment: The text of Craig says, \"Hello\" is actually being returned to the calling HTML page and it's erroring because of an invaild jSon string.

Answer (score 0):

That a json string inside an json output, so you need to parse it twice.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 4627:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627)

> All Unicode characters may be placed within the
> quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped:
> quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000
> through U+001F).

This simply means that nothing is wrong. **The character is being escaped according to the json standard.**

Comment: So is there any way that I can strip out these \'s?

Comment: When you parse/convert the json into an object they are automatically 'stripped out' as needed. So, just use any json parser/converter. If your application is 'erroring because of an invaild jSon string' then there is something else that is invalid (or the json parser/converter is not working). You should **not** manually remove the character before parsing/converting because **then you will get an invalid json string**.